Printing command by reading CSV file with AWK into a bash array
I have the following CSV file (mycsv.csv):
love,hate,--command yes this is bad --other-command
fox,duck,--command yes this is bad --other-command
turtle,rabbit

This means the command would be --command "command_argument" --other-command
Then I'm creating an array:
my_csv="/home/sometimesihatebash/mycsv.csv"
first_column=( $(awk -F "\"*,\"*" '{print $1}' $my_csv) )
second_column=( $(awk -F "\"*,\"*" '{print $2}' $my_csv) )
IFS=$'\n' command=( $(awk -F "\"*,\"*" '{print $3}' $my_csv) )

Then printing all columns into a command
for i in "${!first_column[@]}"; do
    echo "${first_column[i]}"
    echo "${second_column[i]}"
    echo "${command[i]}"
    
    execute_program_name --first "${first_column[i]}" --second "${second_column[i]}" "${command[i]}"

done

But then, for the third row (which has an empty third column), I get:
error: 1 unrecognized argument:
'

And for the first two rows, I get:
no such option: --command yes this is bad --other-command

When echoing each array element, I don't see any problems.
Pasting the exact output of echo also runs the program normally.
Running the for loop with just the first_column and second_column arrays works fine
Probably this has something to do with special characters in the last array but I`m lost
Any ideas?

This seems like a crazy overcomplication. Why would you save commands in a CSV file in the first place? And in the implausible case that this would make sense, why would you read the parts into different arrays?

@tripleee Because bash doesn't have 2-dimensional arrays?

For the first error, you should check whether "${command[i]}" is empty before trying to use it.

For the second error, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136948/why-does-shell-ignore-quoting-characters-in-arguments-passed-to-it-through-varia?noredirect=1&lq=1 to understand why it's happening. However, the usual solution is to put your command and arguments in an array, but that requires multi-dimensional arrays.

bash simply seems like the wrong language for this, you need a language with better data structures. Python would be good.

I agree its complicated, but not useless. We have lots of data in tabular format with sample names, files, tags etc. I'm simplifying the process of getting that information directly into a command line so less bash prone people can prepare that information and can use it easily. This will save me tons of times in the future

@Barmar some lines are empty, when echoing "${command[2]}" I get absolutely nothing which is what I was expecting. That is why i'm not sure why I'm getting the first error!

The first error is because execute_program_name expects a non-empty program name, but "${command[2]}" is empty. You need something like if [ -n "${command[2]}" ] before trying to use it.

if you move turtle,rabbit so that it's the 1st line in the file you'll find that your command[] array entries get shifted because there's no place holder for the missing column in the 1st line (ie, --command yes this is bad --other-command is loaded into positions 0 and 1 as opposed to positions 1 and 2); net result is you'll need to rethink the population of your command[] array to address rows with a missing 3rd column

@markp-fuso I see! That is why I'm getting ' is not a valid option when the index content for that position in the array is null. Seems like my solution by echoing the command into a new array does work. If you have any considerations for that solution that I posted please do say. Thanks!

consider updating the question with what the execute_program_name invocation would look like if you were manually entering them at the command prompt so that we can see where you would (not) use single quotes

do you need the arrays for any other purpose other than this single for loop?

Add the expected output (commands)

It is not clear from your problem description, which statement in your loop produces the error message.

The right answer depends on what --command yes this is bad --other-command is supposed to mean to execute_program_name - if you were to write the command line would that be execute_program_name --command 'yes this is bad' --other-command or execute_program_name --command 'yes' 'this' 'is' bad' --other-command or something else? Please [edit] your question to show us that.

If your CSV contained --command --other-command what would that mean? Should it be treated as execute_program_name --command '' --other-command would be or as execute_program_name --command '--other-command' would be or something else? Please [edit] your question to show that too.

I agree. I updated the question to make more clear that execute_program_name --command ''command_argument" --other-command is what is supposed to be on the third column.

Assumptions:

the input string --command yes this is bad --other-command needs to be passed to execute_program_name in the following format: --command 'yes this is bad' --other-command
the 3rd column consists of long form options (ie, options always start with --)
if the 3rd column is populated the first string will always be a long form option (ie, string will always have the format --option)
the contents of mycsv.csv only need to be parsed for this one for loop; net result: we'll only need a single array (args[]); (see 2nd half of answer for an approach that allows for a single parse and multiple re-use)

We'll make some changes to OP's inputs to demonstrate handling options with and without arguments:
$ cat mycsv.csv
love,hate,--command yes this is bad --other-command
fox,duck,--command yes this is bad --other-command single_string
turtle,rabbit 
sweet,sour,--new-command --newer-command

A simple script to list input parameters:
$ cat execute_program_name
#!/bin/bash

echo "### $0 $@"
cnt=0

for arg in "$@"
do
    ((cnt++))
    echo "arg #${cnt} : ${arg}"
done

One bash approach
$ cat parse_n_run
#!/bin/bash

while IFS=, read -r c1 c2 c3
do
    printf "\n########### %s : %s : %s\n\n" "${c1}" "${c2}" "${c3}"

    args=( "--first" "${c1}" "--second" "${c2}" )       # store first 2 sets of options in array

    while read -r option string
    do
        [[ -z "${option}" ]] && continue                # skip first line (blank)
        args+=( "${option}" )                           # add "--option" to array
        [[ -n "${string}" ]] && args+=( "${string}" )   # if there's an argument then add to the array

    done <<< "${c3//--/$'\n'&}"                         # split c3 into lines by placing a "\n" before each "--"

    typeset -p args                                     # display contents of array
    echo ""
    execute_program_name "${args[@]}"
done < mycsv.csv

Taking for a test drive:
$ parse_n_run

########### love : hate : --command yes this is bad --other-command

declare -a args=([0]="--first" [1]="love" [2]="--second" [3]="hate" [4]="--command" [5]="yes this is bad" [6]="--other-command")

### ./execute_program_name --first love --second hate --command yes this is bad --other-command
arg #1 : --first
arg #2 : love
arg #3 : --second
arg #4 : hate
arg #5 : --command
arg #6 : yes this is bad
arg #7 : --other-command

########### fox : duck : --command yes this is bad --other-command single_string

declare -a args=([0]="--first" [1]="fox" [2]="--second" [3]="duck" [4]="--command" [5]="yes this is bad" [6]="--other-command" [7]="single_string")

### ./execute_program_name --first fox --second duck --command yes this is bad --other-command single_string
arg #1 : --first
arg #2 : fox
arg #3 : --second
arg #4 : duck
arg #5 : --command
arg #6 : yes this is bad
arg #7 : --other-command
arg #8 : single_string

########### turtle : rabbit  :

declare -a args=([0]="--first" [1]="turtle" [2]="--second" [3]="rabbit ")

### ./execute_program_name --first turtle --second rabbit
arg #1 : --first
arg #2 : turtle
arg #3 : --second
arg #4 : rabbit

########### sweet : sour : --new-command --newer-command

declare -a args=([0]="--first" [1]="sweet" [2]="--second" [3]="sour" [4]="--new-command" [5]="--newer-command")

### ./execute_program_name --first sweet --second sour --new-command --newer-command
arg #1 : --first
arg #2 : sweet
arg #3 : --second
arg #4 : sour
arg #5 : --new-command
arg #6 : --newer-command


If OP needs to parse mycsv.csv and (re)use multiple times, and OP has access to bash 4.3+, I'd probably opt to use a nameref to manage arrays args_1[], args_2[], ..., args_n[].
Making a few tweaks to the current script:
$ cat parse_n_run
#!/bin/bash

cnt=0

##########
# parse and store

echo "Parsing ..."

while IFS=, read -r c1 c2 c3
do
    printf "\n########### %s : %s : %s\n\n" "${c1}" "${c2}" "${c3}"

    ((cnt++))
    declare -n _args="args_${cnt}"                          # name ref

    _args=( "--first" "${c1}" "--second" "${c2}" )

    while read -r option string
    do
        [[ -z "${option}" ]] && continue
        _args+=( "${option}" )
        [[ -n "${string}" ]] && _args+=( "${string}" )
    done <<< "${c3//--/$'\n'&}"

    typeset -p "${!_args}"
done < mycsv.csv

### at this point we have 4 arrays: args_1[], args_2[], args_3[] and args_4[]

##########
# make use of arrays

printf "\n###########\n"
echo "Using ..."

for ((i=1; i<=cnt; i++))
do
    declare -n _args="args_$i"

    printf "\n### %s\n\n" "${!_args}"

    execute_program_name "${_args[@]}"
done

Taking for a test drive:
NOTE: notice the 4 declare -a lines reference our 4 arrays args_1[], args_2[], args_3[] and args_4[]
$ parse_n_run
Parsing ...

########### love : hate : --command yes this is bad --other-command

declare -a args_1=([0]="--first" [1]="love" [2]="--second" [3]="hate" [4]="--command" [5]="yes this is bad" [6]="--other-command")

########### fox : duck : --command yes this is bad --other-command single_string

declare -a args_2=([0]="--first" [1]="fox" [2]="--second" [3]="duck" [4]="--command" [5]="yes this is bad" [6]="--other-command" [7]="single_string")

########### turtle : rabbit  :

declare -a args_3=([0]="--first" [1]="turtle" [2]="--second" [3]="rabbit ")

########### sweet : sour : --new-command --newer-command

declare -a args_4=([0]="--first" [1]="sweet" [2]="--second" [3]="sour" [4]="--new-command" [5]="--newer-command")

###########
Using ...

### args_1

### execute_program_name --first love --second hate --command yes this is bad --other-command
arg #1 : --first
arg #2 : love
arg #3 : --second
arg #4 : hate
arg #5 : --command
arg #6 : yes this is bad
arg #7 : --other-command

### args_2

### execute_program_name --first fox --second duck --command yes this is bad --other-command single_string
arg #1 : --first
arg #2 : fox
arg #3 : --second
arg #4 : duck
arg #5 : --command
arg #6 : yes this is bad
arg #7 : --other-command
arg #8 : single_string

### args_3

### execute_program_name --first turtle --second rabbit
arg #1 : --first
arg #2 : turtle
arg #3 : --second
arg #4 : rabbit

### args_4

### execute_program_name --first sweet --second sour --new-command --newer-command
arg #1 : --first
arg #2 : sweet
arg #3 : --second
arg #4 : sour
arg #5 : --new-command
arg #6 : --newer-command


I think this is the most developed answer and others might find this to be helpful depending on each use case

I think I ended up finding a solution...
It is not pretty because it uses eval, which can be a source of problems on itself
The solution lies on opening a new array with the correct commands on each line first:
configs=()
for i in "${!first_column[@]}"; do
    echo "${first_column[i]}"
    echo "${second_column[i]}"
    echo "${command[i]}"
    
    configs+=( $(echo "execute_program_name --first "${first_column[i]}" --second "${second_column[i]}" "${command[i]}"") )

done

Then run:
for i in "${configs[@]}"; do
    eval $i
done

I'm not sure if one line of your input does not run properly, if the next will. But it has worked on my example

That's a useless use of echo; just assign configs+=("execute_program_name" "--first" "${first_column[i]}" "--second" "${second_column[i]}" "${command[i]}") if that's what you mean, though I'm guessing you should properly just add a single string.

Also a useless use of eval. This works: for i in "${configs[@]}"; do $i; done

I will test and update here!

I think this is most elegantly solved with awk and Bash with process substitution and a while loop.
Given:
$ cat file.csv
love,hate,--command yes this is bad --other-command
fox,duck,--command yes this is bad --other-command
turtle,rabbit

You can do this:
configs=()
while read fst sec cmd; do
    configs+=("execute_program_name --first $fst --second $sec $cmd")
done < <(awk -F, '{print $1, $2, $3}' file.csv)

Result:
$ printf "%s\n" "${configs[@]}"
execute_program_name --first love --second hate --command yes this is bad --other-command
execute_program_name --first fox --second duck --command yes this is bad --other-command
execute_program_name --first turtle --second rabbit 

You can see you have a 3 element array:
$ declare -p configs
declare -a configs=([0]="execute_program_name --first love --second hate --command yes this is bad --other-command" [1]="execute_program_name --first fox --second duck --command yes this is bad --other-command" [2]="execute_program_name --first turtle --second rabbit ")

This only works with fields without whitespaces, but that is how your example is written.
If you want that to be executed you don't need eval at all. Just execute each constructed string. In this case, I will use echo as a placeholder for execute_program_name so the rest of the string constructed is echo'ed:
while read fst sec cmd; do
    echo "--first ${fst} --second ${sec} ${cmd}"
done < <(awk -F, '{print $1, $2, $3}' file.csv)

Prints:
--first love --second hate --command yes this is bad --other-command
--first fox --second duck --command yes this is bad --other-command
--first turtle --second rabbit 

The same approach can be used with an array of the constructed strings -- loop over the array and then just hand Bash the string. The Bash default if handed a string is to try and execute that string.
So this works:
for i in "${configs[@]}"; do
    $i                       # look ma! no eval!!!
done


Let's assume that:

your CSV format is simple (no quoted fields with commas, no newlines in fields...),
your bash is recent enough to support arrays and regular expressions matching (=~).

You could try:
while IFS=, read -r x y z; do
  read -r x <<< "$x"; read -r y <<< "$y"
  declare -a a=()
  while [[ $z =~ (.*)(--[^[:space:]]*)(.*) ]]; do
    read -r z <<< "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"; read -r v <<< "${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
    if [[ -n $v ]]; then a=("$v" "${a[@]}"); fi
    a=("${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" "${a[@]}")
  done
  if [[ -n $z ]]; then a=("$z" "${a[@]}"); fi
  execute_program_name --first "$x" --second "$y" "${a[@]}"
done < mycsv.csv

Note: the read -r variable <<< "value" is just a way to trim leading and trailing spaces.
The idea is to build an array of options (a) and pass "${a[@]}" to your command such that all options and their value are properly separated in distinct words.
IFS=, read -r x y z stores the first and second option values in x and y. The rest of the line is stored in z. Next, we process z in a while loop to extract the other options, starting from the last (because regular expressions matching is greedy).
